# Conditional Expectation of Brownian motion using projection

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Assume that $W_s,W_t$ are Standard Brownian motions with $s<t$. Find the following
$$E[W_s | W_t]=? $$
The hint is to use projection method. If I understand correctly, we have the following property by projection
$$E[W_sZ]=E[YZ] $$ for $Y=E[W_s|W_t]$ and $Z$ is some random variable that is measurable under the same filtration that generates $W_t$. How to use this property and proceed? Any hint is appreciated.

P.S. I do not understand the solution given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336864/brownian-motion-conditional-expectation-question) and would prefer to understand using projection method (if at all possible).

Comment: The linked solution kind of does what you are asking

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see the connection. For example, the answer in the link doesn't use the conditional expectation projection property that I've written. So I am a bit puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is that we're going to guess that $Y=\mathbb{E}[W_s | W_t] = \beta W_t$ where $\beta$ is a (non-random) constant that depends only on $s$ and $t$.  Then the projection method tells us (letting $Z = W_t$) that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[W_s W_t] &= \mathbb{E}[Y W_t] \\
&= \beta \mathbb{E}[W_t^2].
\end{align*}

Now we know $\mathbb{E}[W_s W_t] = s$ and $\mathbb{E}[W_t^2]=t$, so the equation simplifies to $s = \beta t$ and hence $\beta = \frac st$.  Therefore we conclude that $\mathbb{E}[W_s | W_t] = \beta W_t = \frac st W_t$.

Comment: Thanks! Why do we take that guess? Does it have to do with $W_s$ and $W_t$ being Gaussian?

Comment: Yeah, it's because the projection property $\mathbb{E}[XZ]=\mathbb{E}[YZ]$ for some $Z$ that's measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G$ is not generally enough to prove that $Y = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal G]$; it only shows that $X-Y$ is uncorrelated with $Z$.  But because $X-Y$ and $Z$ are jointly Gaussian in this case, uncorrelated implies independent, so we know that we actually do have $Y = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal G]$.  We can always make that guess, but we won't have that it always gives the correct conditional expectation like we do with Gaussians.